# Scraping user behavior in a specific web page

Tags: web-scraping

Let's say I want to go to a specific web page and track their users activity (for example get their location, how many times they logged on, the links they clicked etc..) Its is easy to implement this if it was my website, however I want to do it for any website.

Is it technologically doable? Do you have any idea how i can start to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

If the website publicly (with or without authentication) gives Users data, you can do web scraping.
The data that you mentioned are the website stats which can be tracked only by the website or the Web server. Unless you have access to the server logs, you can't do it.